# matlab making a custom vpasolve

Tags: matlab, function, customization

LAST EDIT
Posted a link to another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38554041/matlab-make-if-decide-writing-someting-inside-a-function) with the same problem.
Some things should not be done in matlab... maybe someone else will ask this so my conclusion is in the link above.

My coding is hard to read for me and I often make mistakes, so I think a function would help.

EDIT 2 moved old question to the end of it all and improved it

I would like `vpasolve` to at least automatically add equations or remove them if the unknown is relevant to be calculated.

So let's say I have 4 unknowns: `r1, r2, r3, r4` and 4 equations. How can this be done:

```
syms if r1<=0 
r1=0
else
'r1'
same for the other `r`'s;
[if r1<=0 
r1=0
else
'r1'
same for the other `r`'s] = vpasolve([if r1<=0 
` `
else
'equation1'
same for the other `r`'s], [if r1<=0 
r1=0
else
'r1'
same for the other `r's]);
```

The condition might not always be as easy as >=0...

Also better ways to do it are welcomed as it takes some time to do all this (moved at the end) using`for j=2:~40`. A big time problem could be solved if I also understood why aren't all of my CPU cores used.

Thank you,
Dan.

MOVED CONTENT

I would like `vpasolve` to solve `n` equations, based on a given `n`. My `n` can be 12 or 16, also in the future there will be more than these 2 possibilities. So something like:

```
function y=custvpas(a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,n)
if n=12
...
else
...
end
```

EDIT 1: I have deleted the original `vpasolve` code as this one is far better and I have added the way it works now.

```
om(1)=2.76;  
om(2)=27.5/56; 
om(3)=23.5/56; 
om(4)=1;    
om(5)=5/1000;  
om(6)=50/1000;
om(7)=1/1000;
vb0max=uint8((om(1)+om(3))*10); 
cct(1)=om(1)*om(5)/om(6);  
c=zeros(15,vb0max);   
ct=zeros(4,vb0max);   
v=zeros(4,vb0max);   
a=zeros(3,vb0max);   
v(1,1)=om(6);
ct(1,1)=2*cct(1);
ct(2,1)=om(2)*om(5)/v(1,1);
ct(3,1)=om(3)*om(5)/v(1,1);
cct(4)=cct(1)+ct(2,1)+3/2*ct(3,1); 

t = animatedline;
axis([0,vb0max+3,0,7])

for j=1:1
func12
v(1,j+1)=v(1,j)+om(7);  
v(2,j+1)=v(2,j)+om(7); 
c(14,j)=10^(-14)/c(1,j); 
pH(j)=-log10(c(1,j));addpoints(t,v(2,j)*1000,pH(j));drawnow
pause(0.05)
end


for j=2:vb0max+3
v(1,j)=v(1,j-1)+om(7);v(2,j)=v(2,j-1)+om(7);c(15,j)=v(2,j)*om(4)/v(1,j);

if 6*10^(-38)>(c(3,j-1)*v(1,j-1)-0.0001)/v(1,j)*(10^(-14)/(c(1,j-1)*v(1,j-1)-0.0007)/v(1,j))^3
ct(1,j)=(ct(1,j-1)*v(1,j-1)-om(4)*om(7))/v(1,j);
ct(2,j)=ct(2,j-1)*v(1,j-1)/v(1,j);
ct(3,j)=ct(3,j-1)*v(1,j-1)/v(1,j);
v(3,j)=om(7);v(4,j)=0;
func12
c(14,j)=10^(-14)/c(1,j);

else
ct(2,j)=ct(2,j-1)*v(1,j-1)/v(1,j);
func16
if isequal(size(r1), size([0]))
ct(1,j)=(ct(1,j-1)*v(1,j-1)-om(4)*r111)/v(1,j);
ct(3,j)=(ct(3,j-1)*v(1,j-1)-om(4)*r333)/v(1,j);
v(3,j)=r111;v(4,j)=r333;
else
ct(1,j)=(ct(1,j-1)*v(1,j-1)-om(4)*om(7))/v(1,j);
ct(3,j)=ct(3,j-1)*v(1,j-1)/v(1,j);
v(3,j)=om(7);v(4,j)=0;
func12
end
c(14,j)=10^(-14)/c(1,j);
end

pH(j)=-log10(c(1,j));addpoints(t,v(2,j)*1000,pH(j));drawnow
pause(0.05);
end
```

this is my `func12`

```
r1t=ct(1,j);r2t=ct(2,j);r3t=ct(3,j);
syms r1 r2 r3 r4 r5 r6 r7 r8 r9 r10 r11 r12;
[r1, r2, r3, r4, r5, r6, r7, r8, r9, r10, r11, r12] = vpasolve([r1t==r1+r5+r6+r8,
r2t==r2+r6+r7,
r3t==r3+r8+r9+r10+r11+r12,
cct(4)==r4+r5+r6+r7+r8+r9+2*r10,
r5==r4*r1*10^1.98,
r6==r4*r1*r2*10^1.08,
r7==r4*r2*10^2.25,
r8==r4*r1*r3*10^2.48,
r9==r4*r3*10^4.04,
r10==r4^2*r3*10^5.38,
r11==1.9*10^(-3)*r3/r1,
r12==2.5*10^(-3)*r3/r1^2], [r1, r2, r3, r4, r5, r6, r7, r8, r9, r10, r11, r12]);
index = find(r12>=0);  r10 = r10(index);r1 = r1(index);r2 = r2(index);r3 = r3(index);r4 = r4(index);r5 = r5(index);r6 = r6(index);r7 = r7(index);r8 = r8(index);r9 = r9(index);r11 = r11(index);r12 = r12(index);index = find(r11>=0);  r10 = r10(index);r1 = r1(index);r2 = r2(index);r3 = r3(index);r4 = r4(index);r5 = r5(index);r6 = r6(index);r7 = r7(index);r8 = r8(index);r9 = r9(index);r11 = r11(index);r12 = r12(index);index = find(r10>=0);  r10 = r10(index);r1 = r1(index);r2 = r2(index);r3 = r3(index);r4 = r4(index);r5 = r5(index);r6 = r6(index);r7 = r7(index);r8 = r8(index);r9 = r9(index);r11 = r11(index);r12 = r12(index);index = find(r9>=0);  r10 = r10(index);r1 = r1(index);r2 = r2(index);r3 = r3(index);r4 = r4(index);r5 = r5(index);r6 = r6(index);r7 = r7(index);r8 = r8(index);r9 = r9(index);r11 = r11(index);r12 = r12(index);index = find(r8>=0);  r10 = r10(index);r1 = r1(index);r2 = r2(index);r3 = r3(index);r4 = r4(index);r5 = r5(index);r6 = r6(index);r7 = r7(index);r8 = r8(index);r9 = r9(index);r11 = r11(index);r12 = r12(index);index = find(r7>=0);  r10 = r10(index);r1 = r1(index);r2 = r2(index);r3 = r3(index);r4 = r4(index);r5 = r5(index);r6 = r6(index);r7 = r7(index);r8 = r8(index);r9 = r9(index);r11 = r11(index);r12 = r12(index);index = find(r6>=0);  r10 = r10(index);r1 = r1(index);r2 = r2(index);r3 = r3(index);r4 = r4(index);r5 = r5(index);r6 = r6(index);r7 = r7(index);r8 = r8(index);r9 = r9(index);r11 = r11(index);r12 = r12(index);index = find(r5>=0);  r10 = r10(index);r1 = r1(index);r2 = r2(index);r3 = r3(index);r4 = r4(index);r5 = r5(index);r6 = r6(index);r7 = r7(index);r8 = r8(index);r9 = r9(index);r11 = r11(index);r12 = r12(index);index = find(r4>=0);  r10 = r10(index);r1 = r1(index);r2 = r2(index);r3 = r3(index);r4 = r4(index);r5 = r5(index);r6 = r6(index);r7 = r7(index);r8 = r8(index);r9 = r9(index);r11 = r11(index);r12 = r12(index);index = find(r3>=0);  r10 = r10(index);r1 = r1(index);r2 = r2(index);r3 = r3(index);r4 = r4(index);r5 = r5(index);r6 = r6(index);r7 = r7(index);r8 = r8(index);r9 = r9(index);r11 = r11(index);r12 = r12(index);index = find(r2>=0);  r10 = r10(index);r1 = r1(index);r2 = r2(index);r3 = r3(index);r4 = r4(index);r5 = r5(index);r6 = r6(index);r7 = r7(index);r8 = r8(index);r9 = r9(index);r11 = r11(index);r12 = r12(index);index = find(r1>=0);  r10 = r10(index);r1 = r1(index);r2 = r2(index);r3 = r3(index);r4 = r4(index);r5 = r5(index);r6 = r6(index);r7 = r7(index);r8 = r8(index);r9 = r9(index);r11 = r11(index);r12 = r12(index);
c(1,j)=r1;c(2,j)=r2;c(3,j)=r3;c(4,j)=r4;c(5,j)=r5;c(6,j)=r6;c(7,j)=r7;c(8,j)=r8;c(9,j)=r9;c(10,j)=r10;c(11,j)=r11;c(12,j)=r12;
```

this is my `func16`

```
r2t=ct(2,j);
syms r1 r2 r3 r4 r5 r6 r7 r8 r9 r10 r11 r12 r1t r3t r111 r333;[r1,r2,r3,r4,r5,r6,r7,r8,r9,r10,r11,r12,r1t,r3t,r111,r333]=vpasolve([
r1t==r1+r5+r6+r8,
r2t==r2+r6+r7,
r3t==r3+r8+r9+r10+r11+r12,
cct(4)==r4+r5+r6+r7+r8+r9+2*r10,
r5==r4*r1*10^1.98,
r6==r4*r1*r2*10^1.08,
r7==r4*r2*10^2.25,
r8==r4*r1*r3*10^2.48,
r9==r4*r3*10^4.04,
r10==r4^2*r3*10^5.38,
r11==1.9*10^(-3)*r3/r1,
r12==2.5*10^(-3)*r3/r1^2
6*10^(-38)==r3*(10^(-14)/r1)^3,
r1t==(ct(1,j-1)*v(1,j-1)-om(4)*r111)/v(1,j),
r3t==(ct(3,j-1)*v(1,j-1)-om(4)/3*r333)/v(1,j),
om(7)==r111+r333
], [r1,r2,r3,r4,r5,r6,r7,r8,r9,r10,r11,r12,r1t,r3t,r111,r333]);
index = find(r10>=0);  r10 = r10(index);r1 = r1(index);r2 = r2(index);r3 = r3(index);r4 = r4(index);r5 = r5(index);r6 = r6(index);r7 = r7(index);r8 = r8(index);r9 = r9(index);r11 = r11(index);r12 = r12(index);r111 = r111(index);r333 = r333(index);r1t = r1t(index);r3t = r3t(index);.....r12 = r12(index);r111 = r111(index);r333 = r333(index);r1t = r1t(index);r3t = r3t(index);
```

Comment: We can't suggest a general way to determine each equation in your linear system if we can't see a pattern from `n = 12` and `n = 16`. To me, each case looks like the equations are all random.

Comment: don't understand... what kind of patern?

Comment: What is the logic taken to go from `n = 12` to `n = 16`?  I don't see the logical steps required to go between those two cases.  To me each equation looks almost random and there is no relationship between the two values of `n`.  Because I (or perhaps others) can't see this relationship, I can't suggest a general way to determine each equation dynamically for different values of `n`.

Comment: right, will modify as I have done it another way