# matlab auto removing irrelevant equations from vpasolve

Tags: matlab

I have a number of equations that I am trying to solve with `vpasolve`.

```
ct(1,j)==r1+r5+r6+r8,
ct(2,j)==r2+r6+r7,
ct(3,j)==r3+r8+r9+r10+r11+r12,
r5==c(4,j)*r1*10^1.98,
r6==c(4,j)*r1*r2*10^1.08,
cct(4)/v(1,j)-c(4,j)-r5-r6-r8-r9-2*r10==c(4,j)*r2*10^2.25,
r8==c(4,j)*r1*r3*10^2.48,
r9==c(4,j)*r3*10^4.04,
r10==c(4,j)^2*r3*10^5.38,
r11==1.9*10^(-3)*r3/r1,
r12==2.5*10^(-3)*r3/r1^2
```

Until now I used to eliminate negatives (that are irrelevant) with `index=find(r1>=0)...` but now some of the `r`'s don't have any positives.

I am thinking to do:

```
if index=find(r1>=0) is empty
r1=0
```

... until I find all negatives and eliminate them.

The thing is my equations would be self generated  (like in the future, but now I don't know how to do that), I would need a way to auto zero negative `r`'s and eliminate their equations.

I have asked before, but I'm not sure it's the same problem... [matlab making a custom vpasolve](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38107226/matlab-making-a-custom-vpasolve)

Thank you,
Dan.

Comment: Provide full runnable code including variable declarations. I don't see how `find(r1>=0)` would do anything useful with symbolic math. Have you tried using `assumptions` and functions like `isAlways`?

Comment: @horchler I am now trying to set an interval for the unknown I need, `r1` - like here `sol = vpasolve([z == exp1, z == exp2, 0 == exp3],[x y z],[0 1.5; 1.5 2.5;NaN NaN])`